# String/rope came out of Dryer (its NOT the belt), what is this?

Tags: repair, dryer

I have attached a bunch of pictures of what looks like a nylon braided paper rope that came out of the back of our dryer (between the drum and the back wall).  I cannot find any information on our model online, I'm going to contact Kenmore directly, but I'd like to know what I'm looking for.
[image]

This is the picture of the string/rope:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's probable the seal between the drum and the rear wall.  Is the rear wall stationary or part of the drum ?

Comment: I'll second that.

Comment: What model is this dryer?

Comment: The rear wall is stationary.  It is a Kenmore Heavy Duty Fabricmaster, Model C1108584190 (circa ~1995).  Serial: ICE4432093, Type: DR-6

Comment: I couldn't find ANYTHING googling that model number, which is weird.  The edge of the drum and the backwall must turn against each other (I.e rub).  They need a soft quiet material to make that seal--thats what I think you're looking at.....

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm thinking it is too. Yeah, I even contacted an online parts supplier and they cannot find anything, other than the year it was made.  They suggested I contact Kenmore directly.

Comment: @tyson, please provide a proper answer so the question can be resolved.